# How to do meta-analysis and create forest plots using Beta correlation coefficients

Tags: correlation, meta-analysis, meta-regression

Does anyone knows how to do meta-analysis and create forest plots using beta-correlation coefficients?

Comment: Please be more specific. Show what you have done and what you really want to do, preferably with some example data.

Comment: based on observational reported data: all you get are the Beta-correlation coefficients and 95% CIs, has anyone meta-analysed and created forest plots using these data?

Comment: If you only have betas, you are lacking critical information about the actual variation of the independent (and dependent) variables. Thus the studies cannot validly be compared; a meta-analysis does not seem possible.

Answer (score 1):

I am trying to answer despite this being a very old question.
As long as you have standard errors, you can simply pool beta coefficients with inverse variance weighting, for istance using meta or metafor in R.